Why does the LXX have 70 persons in Deuteronomy 10:22?
Please note this questions is about the specific text Deuteronomy 10:22. The question Did 70 or 75 people go down to Egypt with Jacob? does not adequately address the Deuteronomy 10:22 text. That is why I am posting this separate question.
For Deuteronomy 10:22,
Swete's Septuagint has
"ἐν ἑβδομήκοντα ψυχαῖς κατέβησαν οἱ πατέρες σου εἰς Αἴγυπτον, νυνὶ δὲ ἐποίησέν σε Κύριος ὁ θεός σου ὡσεὶ τὰ ἄστρα τοῦ οὐρανοῦ τῷ πλήθει."
And the New English Translation of the Septuagint has
"Your fathers went down to Egypt with seventy persons, and now the Lord your God has made you as the stars in the sky in number."
I was expecting to see 75 persons like we see elsewhere in the Septuagint (i.e., Gn 46:27, Ex 1:5). Any thoughts on why Deuteronomy 10:22 differs?

According to the Dead Sea Scrolls Bible, a translation of the extant scrolls by Abegg, Flint, and Ulrich, the number is seventy five in 4QExod and 4QGen-Exod LXX. They note that in the Masoretic Text and and in the Samaritan Pentateuch, the number is seventy. Their comment was

To date, this is the only known variant from Exodus reflected in any
modern translation.

They also note the number seventy given in Genesis 46:27  MT (missing from the DSS), and seventy five in Acts 7:14.

What about Deuteronomy, are there DSS fragments reflecting the 10:22 portion of the Deuteronomy scroll?

Unfortunately, the Deuteronomy scroll ends at Deuteronomy 10:15. The LXX reads "seventy" in verse 22. Let me add that I think that it's far more likely that the "five" was inadvertently skipped rather than purposefully inserted. As you probably know, the Masoretes in the 6th to the 10th centuries CE made hundreds of "corrections" (their term) that are now called recensions and destroyed the variant texts.

It's helpful if you can look for duplicate questions before answering, especially for very famous disputes like this one.

Actually, in Genesis or in other parts, the number is 75 because the LXX counted the numbers of the souls of Jacob's house who went or were now staying with Jacob to include Joseph's family. But, when Jacob entered Egypt the count only included the members who entered with Jacob, which was seventy. No contradiction.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I plus oned this answer because it adds an interesting theory as to why the LXX has a different number in Deuteronomy 10:22 than elsewhere: in short, that what is being counted is actually different. The answer still needs work though because it doesn't attempt to substantiate its claims. A good answer would demonstrate with quotations the difference in what is being counted from passage to passage.
